# Can not view Glympse Rest API

Tags: glympse

I need help to find Glympse rest API. For some reason after creating an online account with Glympse, I can not view Rest API. However, I can view SDK for both Android and iPhone.

Question -- does my account need be upgrade and pay for licensing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support question and therefore should be directed to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, but the default "Lite" developer account does not have direct access to the Glympse REST API.

Please refer to this page for more details: https://developer.glympse.com/comparison